# Lemmatize a list of tokens in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, lemmatization

I am trying to lemmatize a column that contains a list of tokens in each cell. I am using the below code for this. Can anyone suggest what changes should be made to get the expected output?

from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

wordnet_lem = WordNetLemmatizer()

df['lemmatized_Tweet'] = df['cleaned_Tweet'].apply(lambda row: list(list(map(wordnet_lem.lemmatize,y)) for y in row))
Input: [absolutely, hearts, breaking, relatives, people, calling, across ]

Output: [[a, b, s, o, l, u, t, e, l, y], [h, e, a, r, t,s], [b, r, e, a, k, i, n, g], [r, e, l, a, t, i, v, e, s], [p, e, o, p, l, e], [c, a, l, l, i, n, g], [a, c, r, o, s, s]]

Expected Output; [absolutely, heart, breaking, relative, people, calling, across

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below. Hope this helps you.

```py
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'tweets': [['absolutely', 'hearts', 'breaking'],['relatives','people', 'calling', 'across']]
    })

wordnet_lem = WordNetLemmatizer()

df['lemmatized_Tweet'] = df['tweets'].apply(lambda row: [ wordnet_lem.lemmatize(i) for i in row] )
print(df)
```